# A Warrning of Numpy loading: The NumPy module was reloaded (imported a second time)

Tags: python, numpy

[Running result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GRZgy.png)
Today, A UserWarning was occurred when I try to import the numpy package, that was not hanppend before.
I use miniconda to manage packages, here is my package list [package list](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TTQ9O.png)

it seems to be another numpy like packag so I reinstalled numpy,but that was not useful.
This was not happend before, I wander how Can I deal with this situation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suppose you didn't uninstall your previous numpy, is there a pip version numpy and you didn't uninstall it? After uninstall all of them you can then use pip to reinstall it.

I recommend you use pip to install package even you are using a conda environment.

Or you can just use conda to create a virtual environment to install numpy

Comment: Thank you for your answer that is efficent,  I have dealed with this problem with following steps：
1. uninstall numpy with pip and conda command 
2. install numpy with conda command
That WORKS!!